# Adding repetitive actions to the create method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How can I make repetitive actions available each time I call the create method on a model. It so happens like each time I write into the database, where each table has a column of createdby - so I just want to write in one place that this column should take on the username in the session!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are [several events in Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events) you can hook into.

It sounds like you're after the `creating`event.

```
User::creating(function($user) {
    $user->created_by = Auth::user()->name;
});
```